# Find three numbers that are divisors of given number and their sum is minimal.

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to work this problem for over a day and i can't come with reasonable solution. We have one given number $N$ ($1< N<10^9$) and we have to find three numbers $M,P,Q$ so they satisfy $M \times P \times Q=N$ and their sum is minimal (the smallest possible). Thank you in advance! Have a great day!

Comment: If the question was posed for *two* numbers, the answer would be the two divisors approximating the square root as much as possible i.e. $M$ is the largest divisor smaller or equal than $\sqrt{N}$ and $P$ is the smallest divisor greater or equal than $\sqrt{N}$. This might help in solving your problem.

Comment: It helps, thank you so much! Have a nice day!

Comment: Take $M=P=Q=N^{1/3}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I think OP is looking for integers.

Comment: Yes, only positive integers.

Comment: Then it should say so in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N={p_1}^{e_1}{p_2}^{e_2}\cdots{p_r}^{e_r}$ be the prime factorization,
and let $\Omega(N) = e_1+e_2+\cdots +e_r$.

You can choose $X,Y,Z$ in two for loops as follows.
$X={p_1}^{x_1}{p_2}^{x_2}\cdots{p_r}^{x_r}$
$Y={p_1}^{y_1}{p_2}^{y_2}\cdots{p_r}^{y_r}$
$Z={p_1}^{z_1}{p_2}^{z_2}\cdots{p_r}^{z_r}$

where $x_i+y_i+z_i = e_i$.

This is  $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ because the number of ways to write $N$ as product  $XYZ$ is:
$$\dbinom{\Omega(N)+2}{2}$$

Comment: And what if you don't know the factorization of $N$?

Comment: Hmm.. $10^9$ is a relatively small number for a computer to handle. He could write a small method like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/JamesOR/RC7SY/) to generate the prime factorization of all the numbers $\lt 10^9$ at the start of his program. I think the OP has it worked out already.. @GerryMyerson

Comment: @GerryMyerson but I'm not too happy with my method. It is really a bruteforce. Would love to see some other clever method that avoids checking every combination..

Comment: It's sort of a bin-packing problem. You have $e_1$ objects of wieght $\log p_1$, $e_2$ objects of wieght $\log p_2$, and so on, and three bins to put them in, and you want to fill the three bins as equally as possible. Bin-packing problems are notoriously resistant to efficient strategies, it doesn't take much to make a bin-packing problem NP-complete.

Comment: I received this problem for homework but I am not allowed to use arrays, so I can't store the factorization of N. Meanwhile, finding the closest divisor possible to the cubic root of N gives me a wrong result. For example, if I have the number 1400352, it gives me 116, 24 and 503, instead of 58, 48 and 503 as answers.